# cifar10.load_data() takes long time to download data

Tags: python, keras

Hi I downloaded the cifar-10 dataset.

In my code, it loads the data set as below.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

from keras.datasets import cifar10
from keras import backend as K
from keras.utils import np_utils

nb_train_samples = 3000 # 3000 training samples
nb_valid_samples = 100 # 100 validation samples
num_classes = 10

def load_cifar10_data(img_rows, img_cols):

    # Load cifar10 training and validation sets
    (X_train, Y_train), (X_valid, Y_valid) = cifar10.load_data()

    # Resize trainging images
    if K.image_dim_ordering() == 'th':
        X_train = np.array([cv2.resize(img.transpose(1,2,0), (img_rows,img_cols)).transpose(2,0,1) for img in X_train[:nb_train_samples,:,:,:]])
        X_valid = np.array([cv2.resize(img.transpose(1,2,0), (img_rows,img_cols)).transpose(2,0,1) for img in X_valid[:nb_valid_samples,:,:,:]])
    else:
        X_train = np.array([cv2.resize(img, (img_rows,img_cols)) for img in X_train[:nb_train_samples,:,:,:]])
        X_valid = np.array([cv2.resize(img, (img_rows,img_cols)) for img in X_valid[:nb_valid_samples,:,:,:]])

    # Transform targets to keras compatible format
    Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_train[:nb_train_samples], num_classes)
    Y_valid = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_valid[:nb_valid_samples], num_classes)

    return X_train, Y_train, X_valid, Y_valid
```

But this takes a long time to download the dataset. Instead I downloaded 'cifar-10-python.tar.gz' manually. So how can I load that into variables, (X_train, Y_train), (X_valid, Y_valid) instead of using, cifar10.load_data()?

Answer (score 3):

Excuse my english. I am trying to load the cifar-10 dataset manually as well. In the following code I unpack `cifar-10-python.tar.gz` to a folder and load the file `data_batch_1` from the folder into 4 arrays: `x_train`, `y_train`, `x_test`, `y_test`. 20% of `data_batch_1` is used for validation as `x_test` and `y_test` and the remaining is used for training as `x_train` and `y_train`.

```
import pickle
import numpy
# load data
with open('cifar-10-batches-py\\data_batch_1','rb') as f:
    dict1 = pickle.load(f,encoding='bytes')

x = dict1[b'data']
x = x.reshape(len(x), 3, 32, 32).astype('float32')

y = numpy.asarray(dict1[b'labels'])

x_test = x[0:int(0.2 * x.shape[0]), :, :, :]
y_test = y[0:int(0.2 * y.shape[0])]
x_train = x[int(0.2 * x.shape[0]):x.shape[0], :, :, :]
y_train = y[int(0.2 * y.shape[0]):y.shape[0]]
```

Comment: small correction, data_batch1-data_batch5 contain the training images, and 'test_batch' contains the test images. You don't have to divide the read dictionary into test and train the way you have. Source: Official dataset webpage

Answer (score 1):

Code here reads training and test images from respective batch files as stated in [dataset website](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html), modification from [this post](https://github.com/deep-diver/CIFAR10-img-classification-tensorflow) with nice explanation.

```
import pickle
import numpy as np

for i in range(1,6):
    path = 'data_batch_' + str(i)
    with open(path, mode='rb') as file:
        # note the encoding type is 'latin1'
        batch = pickle.load(file, encoding='latin1')
    if i == 1:  
        x_train = (batch['data'].reshape((len(batch['data']), 3, 32, 32)).transpose(0, 2, 3, 1)).astype('float32')
        y_train = batch['labels']
    else:
        x_train_temp = (batch['data'].reshape((len(batch['data']), 3, 32, 32)).transpose(0, 2, 3, 1)).astype('float32')
        y_train_temp = batch['labels']
        x_train = np.concatenate((x_train,x_train_temp),axis = 0)
        y_train = np.concatenate((y_train,y_train_temp),axis=0)

path = 'test_batch'
with open(path,'rb') as file:
    # note the encoding type is 'latin1'
    batch = pickle.load(file, encoding='latin1')
    x_test = (batch['data'].reshape((len(batch['data']), 3, 32, 32)).transpose(0, 2, 3, 1)).astype('float32')
    y_test = batch['labels']
```

We can visualise the read data as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_train=x_train.astype(np.uint8)
y_train = np.expand_dims(y_train, axis = 1)

class_names = ['airplane', 'automobile', 'bird', 'cat', 'deer',
           'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck']

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
for i in range(25):
    plt.subplot(5,5,i+1)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.imshow(np.squeeze(x_train[i]), cmap=plt.cm.binary)
    # The CIFAR labels happen to be arrays, 
    # which is why you need the extra index
    plt.xlabel(class_names[y_train[i][0]])
plt.show()
```

Also [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36805640/this-error-while-downloading-datasets-valueerror-i-o-operation-on-closed-file) in case download time is your only problem, you can still use `load_data()`.